# Extract URL from data using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have some script that extracts some text from a table and dumps it into a text file for me. I would like your help to strip out just the URL so that the text file just shows the URL.

```
{
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT post_content_filtered FROM wp_posts ORDER BY post_date desc limit 200");
$tsv  = array();
$html = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
    $tsv[]  = implode("\t", $row);
    $html[] = "<tr><td>" .implode("</td><td>", $row) ."</td></tr>";
}

$tsv = implode("\r\n", $tsv);
$html = "<table>" . implode("\r\n", $html) . "</table>";
$fileName = 'finishedflippa.txt';
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
echo $tsv;
```

`post_content_filtered` text looks something like this:

> blahblahblah http://www.example.com blahblahblah
>   blahblahblah http://www.12345.com blahblahblah
>   blahblahblah http://www.gfds.com blahblahblah
>   blahblahblah http://www.45tyhju.com blahblahblah

The `blahblahblah` is the same for each row. Thanks very much.

Comment: Next time please post a readable code yourself. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry! I had a lot of trouble even getting that far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

URL have very [complex definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax)

You can try this simple match with `preg_match_all`

```
$str = 'text looks something like this: 
blahblahblah http://www.example.com blahblahblah 
blahblahblah http://www.12345.com blahblahblah 
blahblahblah http://www.gfds.com blahblahblah 
blahblahblah http://www.45tyhju.com blahblahblah ' ;

preg_match_all('!https?://[\S]+!', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Comment: This solution is limited to http(s) URLs, while there are many other valid forms of URLs. As OP indicated that the`blahblahblah` prefix is known and fixed - a better approach would be to filter on the prefix (e.g. `!(?:blahblahblah )([\S]+)!`), where `([\S])` should probably be replaced with an expression for a valid URL (which can be quite complex as noted).